# Alamofire request is being cancelled

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

**Background**

I am creating a series of requests to grab a chunk of a file. The chunk size stays the same so the number of requests may change depending on which file I am downloading. For smaller files, and thus smaller number of requests I seem to reliably succeed. However once my request chain reaches the 10+ ballpark I start to get an error.

**Error**

I am getting an error from what appears to be Alamofire.

`Error code -999 cancelled.`

**Looking at other purposed solutions**

From the searching I have done it seems that this occurs when either `the session manager is deallocated` or `another request was kicked off before I received a response from the previous request`.

I made my session manager static, as stated by some other posts to handle the deallocating issue, but I still get this error.

I don't think the next request is being called before the first finishes as my logs seem to be printing out in order and the failure is rather random. I would expect that the requests would overwrite quite reliably.

---

Is there any thing else that causes this error code to occur?

**Additional Logs**

```
NetworkFilesClient.swift:351 - Error downloading chunk URL: MY_URL_HERE, 
Range: bytes=29360128-33554432, 
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" 
UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=MY_URL_HERE, 
NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=MY_URL_HERE}
```

Answer (score 2):

What works for me:

```
sessionManager.session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
```

I put this at the end of my response handling. Why? No clue...

Comment: I'll have to take a look and see if this helps. I have moved on from my attempt at chunking but if I have time I'll cycle back and try it out.